# Как с помощью скрипта можно добавить ссылку к тексту?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ссылки

Приветствую. Есть на сайте копирайт:

```
<p class="copyright">
        © 2015 . Все права защищены. Дизайн и разработка Bla-bla        </p>
```

Как в текст Bla-bla добавить ссылку не изменяя html структуру?

Comment: уже решил `$('.copyright').html('© 2015 . Все права защищены. Дизайн и разработка  <a href="#">Bla-bla</a>');` но, может быть, есть более элегантный способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не изменяя html нельзя, хотя можно его изменить с JavaScriptом:

```js
var $p = $(".copyright");
$p.html($p.html().replace(/(Bla-bla)/, "<a href='url'>$1</a>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="copyright">© 2015 . Все права защищены. Дизайн и разработка Bla-bla </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя jQuery:

```js
 $("p.copyright").html("© 2015 . Все права защищены. Дизайн и разработка Bla-bla <a href='http://www.yourlink.com'>Ваша ссылка<a/>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="copyright">© 2015 . Все права защищены. Дизайн и разработка Bla-bla</p>
```